# How to how image in HTML without saving to file

Tags: php, html, image

I create an image with `imagestring` and a text by PHP. I know `imagepng($image)` without $filepath shows image in web page, but I want to know is it possible to show image by HTML (to use divs and tags) without saving image to a file by `imagepng()`.
I use PHP code below:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$white);
imagestring($image, 5, 31, 50, 'text', $black );
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
#phpinfo();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div>
<!-- want to show image created by imagestring() here -->
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: create the image generator script as a totally separate script - called `blah.php` and use that in an `img` tag - `<img src='blah.php' />`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I want to do this in the same file not to use url for source path

Comment: Alas you cannot output HTML and an image like that in the same file.

Comment: Is it possible prevent imagepng occupying the web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$white);
imagestring($image, 5, 31, 50, 'text', $black );

ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$imagedata = ob_get_clean();
$b64image = base64_encode($imagedata);

$html = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div> 
<img src="data:image/png;base64, $b64image" /> 
</div>
</html>
EOD;

echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: @Hatem unfortunately this did not work. The page shows image by php part ! Just like before adding these changes

Comment: @SaeedEisakhani check the updated code